# Make last command stick to top of terminal window while output scrolls normally

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to print **what command is running and in what directory always as the top line of the window**, even if the output from the command would normally cause it to scroll away. I'd like the normal output to appear below and scroll normally.

How can I do this?

Comment: In bash, you could simply add a DEBUG trap that sets the terminal title before executing the command.  I tend to write this as the tmux status line for the window.  Writing it to the top line of the terminal is risky, since it's very likely to scroll off.

Comment: Furthermore, if you manage to place it on the first line of your terminal and can update it continuously in case of scrolling, then your output will be polluted and scrolling back and forth will become tedious. The tmux option is the way to go forward here.

Comment: This is a highly nontrivial concept. The two current answers ([set the terminal title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56153596/519360) or else poison your scrollback by [constantly overwrite the terminal's top line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56261744/519360)) are I think the best you'll get unless you're willing to run inside tmux or screen and use the status line as described in the bounty comment.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) can't ([yet](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=548845)) put your requested content at the *top* of your view, but it can put it at the *bottom* using a [`caption`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Caption.html) that includes the hard status line (the window title):

```bash
% print 'caption always "%h"\nterm $TERM' > ~/.screenrc
% screen
% precmd() { print -Pn "\e]0;[%~] "; print -Rn "$1"; print -Pn "\e\\"; }
% preexec() { precmd "$1"; }
```

Be careful: that first line will overwrite your `~/.screenrc` and you might not want to do that.

This will give you a color-inverted status line at the bottom of your terminal that contains the path in square brackets and then the current running command (if there is one). Try it in your home directory with `cd /tmp; sleep 1` for example. It'll show `[~] cd /tmp; sleep 1` for a second and then it'll change to `[/tmp]`.

`precmd()` and `preexec()` are [zsh hook functions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions). ZSH runs `precmd()` right before rendering your prompt. Right before executing a command, zsh runs `preexec()` with `$1` set to the entire command. (Use `$2` to traverse aliases.)

The above `precmd()` has three `print` calls to ensure escape codes are restricted from the command line (`-R` suppresses escape sequence interpolation, `-P` enables path variable expansion, and `-n` suppresses the trailing newline). `\e]0;` is one of a few ways of starting a status line and `\e\\` is one of a few ways to end it. The above `preexec()` passes the command into `precmd()`.

Once you've saved your `~/.screenrc`, you can put the following into your `~/.zshrc` to make this always happen:

```bash
if [ -z "$STY" ]; then screen -r 2>/dev/null || screen; fi
precmd() { print -Pn "\e]0;[%~] "; print -Rn "$1"; print -Pn "\e\\"; }
preexec() { precmd "$1"; }
```

The first line launches `screen` if you're not already inside such a session (it tries to resume a detached session if there is one or else it launches a new session). The second two lines are described above.

Be careful, if you close terminals without exiting the shell (and therefore screen), the screen sessions will keep running headless. This is a feature when it comes to remote SSH sessions that get disconnected but it's not as useful locally.

Comment: Amazing, this is really great thanks! So if $1 is itself an alias, is there a way to expand the alias to what it is really running? And also mine does not seem to be printing the directory right now, I am only getting the currently running command. Or rather it prints the directory, and then the command when there is one, but id like both? Maybe I missed something?

Comment: `$2` in `preexec()` has the aliases expanded and some space contracted (see my _zsh hook functions_ link). The rest works for me with both my account (lots of other customizations) and a vanilla account with stock defaults. I do not use oh-my-zsh or anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

A first hack I can think of is to put the command in the title of the terminal emulator.
It will appear in the window title or tab name.
You may have to adjust the settings to display it.

In `~/.zshrc` add or edit this function

```
preexec() {
   print -Pn "\e]0;$1\a"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to achieve this in your terminal session, but could write a function for a command.

```
#! /bin/bash

function _sticky_cmd {
        local cmd=$@
        X=1
        L=$(tput lines)
        ((L=L-1))
        LINES=()
        eval $cmd | while IFS= read -r line; do
                pos=$((X-L))
                [ $pos -ge 0 ] || pos=0
                LINES+=("\n$line")
                echo -en "\033c$cmd : $(pwd)"
                echo -en "${LINES[@]:$pos:$L}" | sed -r 's/^ //g'
                ((X=X+1))
        done
}

_sticky_cmd 'while true; do echo "test $((n=n+1))"; sleep 0.5; done'
```

This will produce:

```
while true; do echo test $((n=n+1)); sleep 0.5; done: /home/user/test/scroll
test 1 
test 2 
test 3 
test 4 
test 5
```

Answer (score 1):

This following works in bash in gnome-terminal (which is xterm-256color).

Save the script below for instance as $HOME/usl (short for "update status line").
Then start a new terminal, and issue the following command in that terminal:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="source $HOME/usl"
```

You now have a status line.
The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# works with:
# gnome-terminal, using VTE version 0.42.5 +GNUTLS
# plus:
# GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

COLOR_BLUE="\e[1;44;37m"
COLOR_NONE="\e[m"

lines=$(tput lines)     # get the number of lines on the terminal

this_cmd=":"

update_status_line()
{
    prev_cmd="$this_cmd"
    this_cmd="`echo "$*" | head -n1`"

    # filter out ourselves
    [ "$this_cmd" == "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && this_cmd=":"    # or choose something different from ':'

    tput sc                 # save cursor position
    tput cup 0 0            # move cursor to row #1 columns #2 (0-based)
    tput el                 # clear from the current position to the end of the line, leaving the cursor where it is

    echo -ne "${COLOR_BLUE}[${prev_cmd}]\t\t${this_cmd}${COLOR_NONE}"

    tput csr 1 "$lines"     # set scroll region to 1-$lines (0-based)
    tput rc                 # restore cursor position

    LINES="$lines"
    stty rows "$lines"
    export LINES
}

# the DEBUG signal is delivered just before the command line is executed by bash;
# that's the moment of opportunity for us
trap 'update_status_line $BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
```